# How can I setup a second db connection with doctrine2 and symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I use doctrine ORM in a Symfony 2.8 project.

My project contains several Bundles. For one Bundle, which generates Reports I want to use the db server with the slave replication as not to stress the master db server.
How to set this up?

What I tried so far:

In the config.yml

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8


            slave:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host_slave%'
                port:     '%database_port_slave%'
                dbname:   '%database_name_slave%'
                user:     '%database_user_slave%'
                password: '%database_password_slave%'
                charset:  UTF8
```

Here I created my second db connection with the values stored in my parameters.yml.

I seem to get the orm configuration I tried to setup in the same file not correctly.
Let my first explain what I need:
I have a "ReportingBundle" which runs a console command. The entity manager is only needed to provide the proper authorization to the needed db server. The queries itself are oure SQL and I don't use the entities.

my service.yml for this bundle:

```
services:
    myproject.reporting.service.csv_report_attachment:
        class: Myproject\ReportingBundle\Service\DefaultCsvReportAttachmentService
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.slave_entity_manager', '@logger', '@myproject.reporting.service.php_template_engine', 'reportingHtmlMailTemplate.php']
```

Now my non functioning orm setup in the config.yml:

## ORM configuration

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        # naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:

            slave:
                connection: slave
                mappings:
                    MyprojectReportingBundle: ~

            default:
                connection: default
                auto_mapping : true
                metadata_cache_driver: redis
                query_cache_driver: redis
                result_cache_driver: redis
```

This results in

```
    [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                             
    Unknown Entity namespace alias 'MyprojectReportingBundle'.
```

I tried to follow the documentation here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle

Question:
What is the correct syntax, so that my query is run on the slave server instead of the default server?

Comment: If you remove the mappings property from your slave entity_managers definition and use auto_mapping:true instead, does it work?

Comment: I tried that.
Then it complains, that you cannot use automapping : true for two entity managers at once.

 [LogicException]                                                                                             
  You cannot enable "auto_mapping" on more than one manager at the same time (found in "slave" and default").

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have everything configured correctly. However, you need to make sure the `Entity` classes are defined in the Bundle namespace. So for example you'd want to have all the entities defined within `Myproject\ReportingBundle\Entity` in your example.

Comment: I have one Entoty defined in this Bundle and another in a sister Bundle.
However I am not sure if they are even used since I "only" have a complex Sql query which I execute. 
then I do a 
    $data = $this->em->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);